# Rspec + Capybara - Paypal Express Sandbox checkout timing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, rspec, capybara, circleci

My test setup is Rspec + Capybara with Poltergeist / Phantomjs.

I'm trying to test the Paypal express sandbox - sometimes the tests pass sometimes not. Looks like a timing problem.

Here's my test snippet which redirects to Paypal and on success back to my page. I'm using my credit on the sandbox account so no creditcard processing...

Anyone has a working setup for that or any suggestions?

```
# confirm order and proceed / redirect to paypal
find('button#booking-button').click

using_wait_time(60) do

  # login on paypal express sandbox page
  within_frame(find('iframe')) do
    fill_in 'email', with: Rails.application.secrets.paypal_test_user_email
    fill_in 'password', with: Rails.application.secrets.paypal_test_user_password
    find('button#btnLogin').click
  end

  using_wait_time(60) do

    # confirm payment and redirect back to my page
    find('input#confirmButtonTop').click

    using_wait_time(60) do

      # check if element on my page exists
      expect(page).to have_selector('div#checkout-thank-you')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Add the exact error message you get and  identify which line it’s from

Comment: Also -- `using_wait_time` sets the default maximum wait time for every capybara action inside the block, so nesting multiple `using_wait_time(60)`s makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jack Kinsella's answer served us very well for 2 years (), but PayPal recently updated their UI in Europe.

You could log in as a guest, but test credit cards are a pain as they keep expiring and filling out the form takes much longer. You'll now first have to accept cookies and indicate that you want to log in.

```
def pay_with_paypal
  paypal_window =
    window_opened_by do
      within_frame(find(".paypal-buttons iframe")) do
        first(".paypal-button").click
      end
    end

  within_window(paypal_window) do
    # similar, just couple of extra steps and calling reusable method for details
    Capybara.using_wait_time(5) do
      # accept cookies
      click_button("Accept Cookies") if page.has_button?("Accept Cookies")

      # switch to login form (if needed)
      click_on("Log In") if page.has_content?("PayPal Guest Checkout")

      add_paypal_login_details
      click_on("Pay Now")
    end
  end
end
```

```
def add_paypal_login_details
  fill_in "login_email", with: "youraccount@test.com"
  click_on "Next"
  fill_in "login_password", with: "yourpassword"
  find("#btnLogin").click
end
```

I've found that PayPal can shift quite a bit depending on region and whether or not you're running headless Chrome. Using `save_and_open_screenshot` could help determine your exact scenario.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what API you are using.

For the REST API (v1), the following worked for me:

```
  # click client side checkout button
  paypal_window = 
    window_opened_by do
      within_frame(find('.paypal-button iframe')) do
        find('.paypal-button-text').click
      end
    end

  # pay within popup window
  within_window(paypal_window) do
    click_link 'Log In'
    # I am assuming you have a buyer email/password in the sandbox set up
    fill_in 'login_email', with: MyConfig['paypal_buyer_email']
    click_on 'Next'
    fill_in 'password', with: MyConfig['paypal_buyer_password']
    click_on 'Log In'
    click_on 'Pay Now'
  end
```

At time of writing (for the old SOAP API not the newer REST API), this works:

```
click_link 'Log In'
using_wait_time(60) do
  fill_in 'login_email', with: 'email'
  click_on 'btnNext'
  fill_in 'password', with: 'password'
  click_on 'btnLogin'
  click_on 'confirmButtonTop'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like they changed their layout. form instead of iframe. here's whats working for me some times:

```
find('button#booking-button').click

using_wait_time(60) do
  within('form.proceed.maskable') do
    fill_in 'email', with: Rails.application.secrets.paypal_test_user_email
    fill_in 'password', with: Rails.application.secrets.paypal_test_user_password
    find('button#btnLogin').click
  end

  using_wait_time(60) do
    find('input#confirmButtonTop').click

    using_wait_time(60) do
      expect(page).to have_selector('div#checkout-thank-you')
    end
  end
end
```